# MaterialUI / Mui Select Dropdown - inconsistent keyboard navigation with numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, accessibility

When you do a select as per documentation https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/
and you use numbers, when using a keyboard to select any duplicate number one would expect it to select the duplicate number.

Example typing in 2 and 4 selects 24 however typing in 2 and 2 selects 20 if 1-9 do not have a 0, if 1-9 are 01, 02, 03 then it selects 21. Typing in 3 and 4 selects 34 however typing in 3 and 3 selects 30

I have provided 2 examples (with and without 0) in the code example below and a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/muiselect-inconsistent-with-keyboard-k3jx6l?file=/demo.tsx:0-2221).

Are there any ways to make this more consistent or is there some form of accessibility standard that I'm not seeing that explains this behavior?

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";
import * as _ from "lodash";

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const [ageTwo, setAgeTwo] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent, isTwo?: boolean) => {
    isTwo
      ? setAgeTwo(event.target.value as string)
      : setAge(event.target.value as string);
  };

  const items = _.range(1, 66).map((item) => {
    return { value: item };
  });

  const itemsWithZero = _.range(1, 66).map((item) => {
    return { value: item < 10 ? `0${item}` : `${item}` };
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">
            Items without Zero
          </InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
            id="demo-simple-select"
            value={age}
            label="Items without Zero"
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, false)}
          >
            {items.map((item) => {
              return (
                <MenuItem key={item.value} value={item.value}>
                  {item.label | item.value}
                </MenuItem>
              );
            })}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </Box>
      <Box sx={{ paddingTop: 5 }}>
        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Items with Zero</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
            id="demo-simple-select"
            value={ageTwo}
            label="Items with Zero"
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, true)}
          >
            {itemsWithZero.map((item) => {
              return (
                <MenuItem key={item.value} value={item.value}>
                  {item.label | item.value}
                </MenuItem>
              );
            })}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
}
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I get that typing 2 is essentially tabbing through the 2's, but shouldn't that only happen after a short delay. Where as if you do 2 & 2 in quick succession i still would imagine it would select 22

Comment: That is weird. It works if you hard code the `MenuItem`s ahead of time, but that's obviously not a good solution. So I suspect it has something to do with the `{items.map((item) => { <MenuItem> ... </MenuItem> } `

Comment: @C.Helling I added a 3rd option to the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/muiselect-inconsistent-with-keyboard-k3jx6l?file=/demo.tsx) for hardcoded values, and i'm seeing the same functionality.  Do you have an example to where this wasn't happening?

Comment: I think you're right, I am mistaken. I was playing with dropdowns like "AB", "AA", "ABA", and I am starting to think this is expected behavior for the select control, that numerals are basically treated as the same leading letter. I guess my suggestion would be to not use a dropdown for a large list of ints, but if you really insist, it appears like the `<NativeSelect>` control behaves more in line with what you expect.

Comment: Let me know if you'd like me to flesh that out as an answer.

Comment: Great catch on the `<NativeSelect>` that does indeed behave in the correct manner. I feel its odd though that the Mui Select behaves different than the Mui NativeSelect. I would still prefer a way to fix MuiSelect if possible or set a custom function to handle the selection logic if possible for a consistent design and feel (as there are higher customizations needed and to use the MuiSelect).

Comment: i may have to write my own onKeyDown function and stop propagation